# Search results not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, search, group-by

I'm trying to update our search process so it works a little better until our site gets a complete revamp in the next 6-7 months. Currently, it's set up so it looks at the tables with the item's name, number, color, and description.

For whatever reason, it didn't work very well that way and it was leaving out a lot of results that should have (and made sense to have) been included. So, to remedy this, I added 2 new tables: pro_item_keyword and pro_item_keyword_look_up.

The keyword table has a Keyword and Keyword_ID. The look up table has an ID and a Keyword_ID. I followed the same setup as the other selects and joins in the file (that had been working decently well, just not retrieving all of the results) when adding the keyword tables.

As soon as I added the lines for the keyword tables and did a search, it told me the number of items that fit what I was searching for, but didn't actually display any of them. I had based it off of the lines dealing with the color mostly, since the color isn't actually displayed on the results page (and the keyword wouldn't be either). I know that the MySQL tables are connecting to the keywords tables because of the additional number of results, and I can look at the pro_search_log table and see what I had searched for and the total results.

I don't understand why it works fine until I add additional tables into the mix. Should the table settings be something specific that I might have missed? Or did I goof up the coding? Any help or suggestions would be awesome! Thank you in advance!

```
//This code uses the values in $rows_per_page and $numrows in order to identify the number of the last page.
$rows_per_page = 25;
$lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);

//This code checks that the value of $pageno is an integer between 1 and $lastpage.
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = 1;
} elseif ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno = $lastpage;
} 

//This code will construct the LIMIT clause for the sql SELECT statement.
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

//Now we can issue the database query and process the result.
if ($vid) {
//This code will count how many rows will satisfy the current query.
$query = "SELECT
    coas50.pro_item.Image,
    coas50.pro_item.Description,
    coas50.pro_long_description.Long_Description,
    coas50.pro_item.Item_Number,
    coas50.pro_color.Swatches,
    coas50.pro_color.Color
    coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword
 FROM pro_item
  LEFT JOIN pro_videos
  ON pro_videos.Item_ID = pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_long_description_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_long_description
    ON coas50.pro_long_description.ID=coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Description_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_color_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color
    ON coas50.pro_color.ID=coas50.pro_color_look_up.Color_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword_ID=coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.Keyword_ID
 WHERE 
   pro_videos.Video_ID = '$vid' 
  GROUP BY coas50.pro_item.ID DESC $limit";
} else {

$query = "SELECT
    coas50.pro_item.Image,
    coas50.pro_item.Description,
    coas50.pro_long_description.Long_Description,
    coas50.pro_item.Item_Number,
    coas50.pro_color.Swatches,
    coas50.pro_color.Color
    coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword
  FROM coas50.pro_item
  JOIN coas50.pro_long_description_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_long_description
    ON coas50.pro_long_description.ID=coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Description_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_color_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color
    ON coas50.pro_color.ID=coas50.pro_color_look_up.Color_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword_ID=coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.Keyword_ID
 WHERE 
    coas50.pro_item.Description LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_long_description.Long_Description LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_item.Item_Number LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_color.Swatches LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_color.Color LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword LIKE '%$search%'
    GROUP BY coas50.pro_item.ID  DESC $limit";

}

$result = mysql_query($query);
$search_noslash = stripslashes($search);
$total_results = (!$vid) ? "<h4>$numrows product results for '$search_noslash'</h4>" :    "<br />";

$XX = "<div id='products'>
<b class='rtop'>
    <b class='r1'></b> <b class='r2'></b> <b class='r3'></b> <b class='r4'></b>
</b>
<table id='results' width='100%' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
    <td id='results_head'><center>$total_results
    <div id='pro_search'>
        <form method='get' action='product_results.php'> 
        <input id='searchBox' title=\"Please enter a keyword, item number, color, or color code\" name=\"search\" type=\"text\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"40\" value=\"Search Again\" onblur=\"this.value = this.value || this.defaultValue;\" onfocus=\"this.value == this.defaultValue && (this.value = '');\">
        <input type='image' src='../template_imgs/search_bn.gif' width='52' height='26' id='fetch' title='fetch'>
        </form>
    </div>
</table>
<br />
    <b class='rbottom'>
<b class='r4'></b><b class='r3'></b><b class='r2'></b><b class='r1'></b>
</b>
</div>";
```

Comment: There's *waaaaaayyyyyy* too much code here. You need to narrow this down further as we are not going to wade through all of this for you.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make sure I didn't leave out anything that was needed! I guess I went a little overboard. ;) I've cut out everything that wasn't the query and how it's displayed.

Comment: You are misusing `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are misusing `GROUP BY`. It's for controlling aggregate (summary) queries. If you don't have any aggregate functions like `COUNT(*)` or `MAX(col)`, `GROUP BY` does unpredictable things in MySQL and fails in standard SQL. Read about `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Second, you don't expect this to be fast, right? A series of `OR`-joined `COLUMN LIKE '%match%` functions are bound to be very slow indeed.

Third, keep in mind that `JOIN` operators eliminate nonmatching rows. You may or may not want `LEFT JOIN` instead.

If I were you I'd troubleshoot this by building up your queries progressively.

Start with the root table and the keyword stuff.

```
SELECT
    coas50.pro_item.ID,
    coas50.pro_item.Image,
    coas50.pro_item.Description,
    coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword
  FROM coas50.pro_item
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword_ID=coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.Keyword_ID
 WHERE 
    coas50.pro_item.Description LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword LIKE '%$search%'
```

See how you do with that. Make sure the results are what you hope for. Then add at a time.

Comment: Everything worked AWESOME this way! I'm not entirely sure how it was different from before, besides adding the lines in gradually (I added item_number and description first, then color and swatch). That tells me I just had a typo or missed something in there. If I used Order By or left that line completely out, it showed multiples of everything (1 item listed 14 times); if I used Group By, it displayed everything as it should. Odd! Thank you for your help and suggestions, I appreciate it!

Comment: If `GROUP BY` is somehow, by accident, helping you, try using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: I changed both `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` and removed both `GROUP BY`lines and it repeated the items 9 times. I guess 9 times is better than 14! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't trust the number of results to be an indicator that your query is correct. I would run a lot of searches that I know the answer to find out if it's working, whenever you get it to work. Use unusual attributes that only one or two products will have, for example if you only have one lavender item.

But back to your join. This is the query you're having trouble with, right?

```
$query = "SELECT
coas50.pro_item.Image,
coas50.pro_item.Description,
coas50.pro_long_description.Long_Description,
coas50.pro_item.Item_Number,
coas50.pro_color.Swatches,
coas50.pro_color.Color
coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword
FROM coas50.pro_item
JOIN coas50.pro_long_description_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_long_description
    ON coas50.pro_long_description.ID=coas50.pro_long_description_look_up.Description_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_color_look_up.Item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_color
    ON coas50.pro_color.ID=coas50.pro_color_look_up.Color_ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
  JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword
    ON coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword_ID=coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.Keyword_ID
 WHERE 
    coas50.pro_item.Description LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_long_description.Long_Description LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_item.Item_Number LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_color.Swatches LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_color.Color LIKE '%$search%'
    OR coas50.pro_item_keyword.Keyword LIKE '%$search%'
    GROUP BY coas50.pro_item.ID  DESC $limit";
```

I think the problem might be in the keyword part of the join if the keywords table follow the same 
naming conventions as the rest of the tables.

```
JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
```

Shouldn't that be

```
JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good answer! Excellent combination of overview and specifics.

Comment: @Bonnie, I don't think it should be `JOIN coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up
ON coas50.pro_item_keyword_look_up.item_ID=coas50.pro_item.ID`
because the column that pro_item_keyword_look_up matches to pro_item is ID, not item_ID. Right? 
Also, I tried searching for a term that previously returned 2 results, with the code above, it returns 6 results. However, based on the keywords table, it should be returning 9. Since I can't see the results that it's returning, I can't tell if it's actually returning part of what it should be! Hmm.

Comment: It's kind of hard to figure out what all the field names actually mean, but I was assuming keyword_look_up.ID is the primary key of the keyword not the foreign item of the item. keyword_look_up.item_ID would be the foreign key ID of the item, which would match the primary key of the item, pro_item.ID. I also based my answer on how all the other joins are written.

Comment: I understand it makes it more difficult without being able to see everything used. I had mentioned in the third paragraph what columns the pro_item_keyword and pro_item_keyword_look_up use. Sorry if that paragraph didn't quite make sense. When I questioned you, I was genuinely making sure how I set it up made sense. :) I set up these two tables with different column names than the other tables because it was a mess trying to figure out how all of them are tied together if you're looking at just the database and not one of the files like this.